# Ember: Loop through records in one model to display records in other model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

A simplified version of the data models I'm working with:

**Browser**

```
var Browser = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  versions: DS.hasMany('version', {async: true}),
});
```

**Version**

```
var Version = DS.Model.extend({
    browser: DS.belongsTo('browser', {async: true}),
    number: DS.attr('string'),
    supports: DS.hasMany('support', {async: true}),
}
```

**Support**

```
var Support = DS.Model.extend({
    support: DS.attr('string'), // yes, no, partial
    version: DS.belongsTo('version', {async: true}),
    feature: DS.belongsTo('feature', {async: true})
});
```

**Feature**

```
var Feature = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    supports: DS.hasMany('support', {async: true}),
});
```

I want to allow the user to select a feature and then display support information for all browser versions. Something like this:

```
Support for featureName in browserName:
- version 4: yes
- version 3: partial
- version 2: no
- version 1: no
```

My current setup has nested routes `features/:feature_id/:browser_id`

I will have all of the records for `browser` and `version` but there are too many records in `support` to download them all from the API.

How can I loop through all the `browser.versions` and display all the `feature.supports` that match that version?

Comment: is ember-data a hard requirement?

Comment: It's a hard requirement for getting the data out of the API and into the app. I also have no control over the API.

Comment: got ya -just wanted to offer some help but I don't use ember-data

Comment: @ToranBillups one day I hope to be good enough with Ember that I could take any suggestions as a starting point for a solution but today is not that day ;)